# Мерикандуем в карикатическом смысле [значение]

Tags: значение-слов

Наткнулся вот на эту фразу в произведении А. Платонова, понимаю, что "коверканье" вперемешку с местным диалектом, но что значит доподлинно - неясно, просветите?

p.s. единственный вариант: рекомендуем в критическом смысле, но неужели в начале XX века на селе было всё так уж "печально" (либо совсем крайняя степень утрирования)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы приводите фразу из рассказа Платонова "Афродита" (1946) :

> И тебе, Назар Иванович, мы все в целости мерикандуем в карикатическом  смысле строить по плану и масштабу, ...

Однако это выражение встречается у автора уже в 1921 году, в зарисовке "Володькин муж", опубликованной под псевдонимом *Скорлупендий* в газете "Воронежская коммуна".

> -- Слухай, Володимир супруг, меняй паровик!
>    -- Что ты, чорт, сколбасился?
>    -- Суть тебе говорю. **Полный сурьез мерикандую в карикатическом смысле...**

Из контекста ясен смысл первого исковерканного слова : *предлагаю*, *представляю*. Возможная его конструкция : МЕРЕКАю + рекомеНДУЮ. Второе слово, скорее всего, соединение *критического* с *карикатурным*. Вполне в духе тогдашней малограмотной эпохи.

Comment: Я бы предположила, что не соединение критического с карикатурным, а скорее искажённый "категорический".